# Parse PHP SDK completely ignores a MasterKey change

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

So in order to keep things secure we decided to change the master key of our Parse Server.

Our iOS kept working because it only requires the app id, that was expected but surprisingly our PHP scripts kept running as well, even though they were initialized with the WRONG MasterKey.

1. Does the Parse PHP SDK completely ignore the master key change?
2. How could we ever prevent old php scripts who happen to have the an application key to access our Parse and "read" data?

According to the docs:

```
 ParseClient::initialize('YOUR_APP_ID', '', 'YOUR_MASTER_KEY');
 ParseClient::setServerURL('http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse');
```

Comment: No PHP SDK does not ignore the master key. Just check that both sdk and the parse-server is running the same key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is the issue. we changed the parse-server masterKey, but left the old master key in php's init. The script somehow manages to still work. We tried various things to prevent php to work. for instance, we enabled the RestKey on the server and now php would only work if the RestKey was provided in the second argument. This would have solved it, but iOS didn't work now. Need to find a way to de-authorize php without de-authorizing iOS.

Comment: did you restart parse-server after you changed it?

Comment: c'mon @Cliffordwh. We've been restarted all night. We tried wrong master key, even NO MASTER KEY let's php still function. I'm baffled.
ParseClient::initialize('d4n1ts8JiyGSDu9OYKSSrEoXG3dx', '', '');

(obviously i changed the appid before posting)

Comment: ill try replicate this quick! give me a sec

Comment: What parse-version are you running? are you using pm2?

Comment: 2.3.1 (latest). What happened when you removed the master key from your php initialize? did it still work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133072/discussion-between-cliffordwh-and-bendigi).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you would be the following.

Use `RestKey` for `PHP` as your second argument and then IOS you can just use `clientKey` as your second argument.

Just ensure that you add both `restKey` and `clientKey` to your construct server side.

my working swift3 example too!

```
 let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = PARSE_APP_KEY
            $0.clientKey = PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
            $0.server = PARSE_URL
            $0.isLocalDatastoreEnabled = true

        }
        Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

**EDIT /QUOTE:**

If you take a look in `ParseClient::initialize` the master key is stored in the static var `$masterKey.` This is used in `ParseClient::_getRequestHeaders` (when master key use is requested) to provide the `X-Parse-Master-Key` header with the master key as the value.

The master key is definitely used, but it depends on the request. If `$useMasterKey` is false for a given request in `ParseClient::_request` (the default value is false as well) the master key will not be added to the request headers. In such a case the master key will not be used, but this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and spending time on it. The issue we have is that iOS is already shipped and in production.

Comment: What are you passing in the initialization for IOS? @bendigi

Comment: just application id and server url. If I can find a way to patch the server for now, it'd be good too. The original docs said not to pass the client id, not needed. I wish now I would have added at least an empty string.

Comment: Yes I know but it would have worked! I've got iOS and the php running as described above. But yes, client id is not needed.

Comment: Just out of interest when you add restkey what error do you get from iOS ? You mentioned php then works but not iOS?

Comment: when we add the rest key and the php does not have the correct key it stops working (which is what we want) but iOS gives authentication errors

Comment: Which is strange because iOS should ignore that key because you never passed it.ill test that quick to be sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133113/discussion-between-bendigi-and-cliffordwh).

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes, the parse php sdk doesn't do any validation on the master key. The validation occurs on the side of the Parse Server you're running. Essentially the master key exists to allow overriding of ACLs as mentioned in the [sdk docs](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/php/guide/#client-vs-server). It is submitted to the server when a request is sent that asks for use of the master key.

Basically, if you make any requests that need to override ACLs and you indicate to use the master key, then the master key will be sent. In other cases the master key *is not sent*. You can test this out by writing up some quick code that will send the master key, like `$object->save(true)`. In this case your master key *should* fail if it does not match what is loaded in the server.

2.) You really can't prevent someone from figuring out your App Id. The security you're looking for is not as much on the client's end as it is on the server's. You should be making sure to setup object and class ACLs to restrict access to all objects (and classes) that you do not want to be read (or written to) by arbitrary individuals. Roles are a fairly good way of applying this to a broad set of objects, like restricting access to an Admin role. If you lock your data down it would require someone to compromise an existing account with access to that given data, rather than just use your App Id.

That being said you should always be wary of someone who might manage to grab your master key, as it would allow them to bypass all of those ACLs you setup (keep it safe!).

I hope this helps to clarify the role of the master key for you guys.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the ACL concept but how would you design this. Class A contains products that can be read by all app users (no matter if they are logged in or not). However, individual product rows belong to a user and should only be modified when that user is logged in. All products can be read and modified by the PHP SDK (where you suggest to use MasterKey). How would you prevent a 3rd party to read Class A without the proper authentication? Did I miss something?

Comment: No problem! For ensuring that rows can only be modified by a user (but can be read by all) you can just set the ACLs such that public can read but only the owning user(s) can write. In regards to a 3rd party reading you can only prevent that if you remove the public read from the ACL. You could replace this will some role like 'Users' and ensure everyone is in it, but this will mean that users who are not logged in will be unable to read now. You're in a bit of a pinch there, you'll have to pick and choose what's public and what's not based on your scenario.

Comment: Thank you.. Pinch is good as long as it doesn't turn into a burn. I really  appreciate the time you spent on this.